# Having a difficult time knowing permutation of combination with regard to questions

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

The question usually doesn't matter, what I do notice that I is that I'm almost always wrong. But I can give an example of a question:

**Q** *Three Americans, three Canadians, three Spaniards, and three Russians are flying on a small plane that consists of 6 rows of two seats each. In how many ways can they be seated, so that no two people from the same country sit in the same row?*

**A** *We first count the number of seatings where two Americans sit in the same row. There are six rows to choose from. **Once the row is chosen, there are 2 $\cdot$ 3 = 6 ways to seat the Americans in a row.***

How I would answer it, and immediately get it wrong from the get-go, is that I would ask myself in how many ways I can choose two people from a certain nationality out of three persons from that nationality.

I would think that order doesn't matter. If I chose person1 and then person2, how does that differ from choosing person2 first and then person1? In other words, I would go for 3C2.

Then you could argue that the seats matter; that, in a given row, it matters where person1 sits and where person2 sit, and hence it is 3 $\cdot$ 2 and ***not*** 3C2. But I don't see how I would get that information from the question as it is.

This same problem for me applies to the rows as well; from the answer it is implied that not only the seat but also the row where a person sits, matters. Again, how does this flow from the question?

**Q2** *Yeechi has a deck of cards consisting of the 2 through 5 of hearts and the 2 through 5 of spades. She deals two cards (at random) to each four players. What is the probability that no player receives a pair?*

**A2** *First we count the number of ways the first player receives a pair. There are four possible pairs (one for each denomination from 2 through 5), and the number of ways the remaining six cards can be dealt to the remaining three players is 6C2 $\cdot$ 4C2 = 90, because we have 6C2 choices for cards for the first remaining player, then 4C2 choices for cards for the next remaining player.*

*Next we count the number of ways both the first player and second player can receive a pair. There are four possible pairs for the first player, and three possible pairs for the second player. (sic)*

Once again, I did not choose for 4 $\cdot$ 3, but for 4C2. For me, there's nothing that indicates that the order matters here. What does it matter that player 1 has pair 1 and player 2 has pair 2, or that player 1 has pair 2 and player 2 has pair 1, **as long as they have a pair!**

I really could use some help in getting my thinking straight about these matters, because this keeps tripping me up continuously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that the first question *could* be perceived to be a bit vague.

Although not infallible, some keywords often help to distinguish between permutations and combinations.

- Permutations: **Arrange, order, ways.**
- Combinations: **Select, choose.**

From a practical point of view, though, the row and particular seat (e.g. window or aisle) **do** matter, and that is how I would interpret it.  What you could do if you have a strong doubt is to spell out the doubts you are having and the  assumptions you are making, or better still, offer two sets of answers.

For the second question, **it doesn't matter**, *probability* is being asked for, and if you compute favorable and total outcomes in a consistent manner, the *ratio* will not change !

Comment: Thanks you for your insight, it is difficult coming up with any reason how or why by yourself.

Comment: You're welcome ! Hopefully, with practice, doubts will dwindle.